# How to I solve the inverse $(e^x – je^x)/(e^x+e^x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I have tried using this method https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-LJWfuoCDs. But I am getting zero on one side thus cancelling $e^x$, which means that the the answer I get will not be in form of ln. Is this correct? Kindly help me solve it

What I did is I let $y$ be $(e^x – je^x)/(e^x+e^x)$.
Then I said $y (2e^x) = e^j - je^x$.
Solving further leads to cancellation of $e^x$. :( :(. i am supposed to teach this to students tomorrow. I don't really know what goes on. I think $J$ is a letter (constant) in this case

Comment: Could you at least put your question in the body of the question. At the moment this is incomprehensible - there is no $e^y$ which looks as though it might be cancelled - and you could explain the  question in words too - is $j$ a general number or are you wanting $j^2=-1$? (the community here is more familiar with $i^2=-1$)

Comment: And where should the missing opening parenthesis go?

Comment: @Vokel Kit: Thanks for the edit. That function is a constant function, simplifying to $y = \frac{1 - j}{2}$, so it has no inverse.

Comment: The original questions says Identify a simple function of the inverse function given. by y = (1-j)/2 according to @mike4ty4 mean the same thing?

Comment: @Vokel Kit: I'm not sure I get what that is asking for. Literally it would seem to say that $\frac{1 - j}{2}$ is the function, a function of *j*, not x, and that it is an inverse function, and a "function of" it would be something like $f(\frac{1 - j}{2})$ for some simple $f$. In which case it could be pretty arbitrary. Are you sure you have that right?

Comment: Can you check again your task, the function might be $$\tanh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$$ or $$\tanh(jx)=j\tan(x)=\frac{e^{jx}-e^{-jx}}{e^{jx}+e^{-jx}}$$ or some variation thereof.

Comment: @LutzL No, that is not it

Comment: Somehow you have to prevent that the x cancels from the expression. The basic "trick" is that you replace $u=e^x$ and have then a fraction of linear functions to solve or at worst, as in the trigonometric functions, a quadratic equation. So put a minus in one of the exponents of numerator and denominator to get a workable example.

Comment: @LutzL but the solution requires a simple function. I dont want to have an anwer with e^x

Comment: What do you mean by "simple"? Do you know if it's trigonometric or not?

Comment: @VokelKit, just tried it, and the inverse is a constant, meaning the function has no inverse.\

Comment: I settled for the constant as the final answer